# Python * changes the variable?

Tags: python

There is a quite simple code below:

```
    data = "123456"

b = iter(data)
print(*b)
print(*zip(b, b))


def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0, s1), (s2, s3), (s4, s5), ..."
    a = iter(iterable)
    return zip(a, a)

print(*pairwise(data))
```

The result is:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6

('1', '2') ('3', '4') ('5', '6')
```

However if we would comment out 4th string like this:

```
#print(*b)
```

The result will be:

```
('1', '2') ('3', '4') ('5', '6')
('1', '2') ('3', '4') ('5', '6')
```

Im a little bit confused since I never thought that * operator might change variables? What is going on here ? :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `print(*b)` consumed the entire iterator - so the next line printed only a newline in your first example.

Comment: `print()` is a statement. Moreover it will consume all the positional args you offer it. So, `*` didn't change the variable (/iterable); the `print()` statement consumed all of the iterable. Using tuple-unpacking. (What do you expect `print` to do? If you call `print(a,b,c,d,e,f)` it's not going to stop printing after `d` is it? It will use all its arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any iteration done to an iterator changes the state of the iterator.  This includes unrolling done by the `*` operator. By the way, this is why `zip(b,b)` doesn't get you `('1', '1') ('2', '2') ('3', '3') ('4', '4') ('5', '5') ('6', '6')`

You would get the same effect if you did `list(b)`, for instance:

```
>>> data = "123456"
>>> b = iter(data)
>>> list(b)
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
>>> print(*zip(b, b))

>>> def pairwise(iterable):
...     "s -> (s0, s1), (s2, s3), (s4, s5), ..."
...     a = iter(iterable)
...     return zip(a, a)
...
>>> print(*pairwise(data))
('1', '2') ('3', '4') ('5', '6')
```

```
>>> data = "123456"
>>> b = iter(data)
>>> print(*zip(b, b))
('1', '2') ('3', '4') ('5', '6')
>>> def pairwise(iterable):
...     "s -> (s0, s1), (s2, s3), (s4, s5), ..."
...     a = iter(iterable)
...     return zip(a, a)
...
>>> print(*pairwise(data))
('1', '2') ('3', '4') ('5', '6')
```

If you want to avoid that, you could unroll it into a tuple (for instance) and just use that tuple:

```
>>> data = "123456"
>>> b = iter(data)
>>> b = tuple(b)
>>> print(*b)
1 2 3 4 5 6
>>> print(*zip(b, b))
('1', '1') ('2', '2') ('3', '3') ('4', '4') ('5', '5') ('6', '6')
>>> def pairwise(iterable):
...     "s -> (s0, s1), (s2, s3), (s4, s5), ..."
...     a = iter(iterable)
...     return zip(a, a)
...
>>> print(*pairwise(data))
('1', '2') ('3', '4') ('5', '6')
```

```
>>> data = "123456"
>>> b = iter(data)
>>> b = tuple(b)
>>> print(*zip(b, b))
('1', '1') ('2', '2') ('3', '3') ('4', '4') ('5', '5') ('6', '6')
>>> def pairwise(iterable):
...     "s -> (s0, s1), (s2, s3), (s4, s5), ..."
...     a = iter(iterable)
...     return zip(a, a)
...
>>> print(*pairwise(data))
('1', '2') ('3', '4') ('5', '6')
```

Notice that in these cases, `zip(b,b)` *does* result in `('1', '1') ('2', '2') ('3', '3') ('4', '4') ('5', '5') ('6', '6')`.

Comment: Indeed this is not very common concept to me yet, need to read more about iterators for sure. Thanks !